# AdSense: Will Google ban me if I list "No ads" as a reason to sign up at my site?

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

Can't find anything about this in Google AdSense's TOS. Basically I want to remove ads for logged in users on my site -- but will Google allow me to use this as a value proposition on my front page?

> Sign up today for extra benefits:
>
> - No ads
> - Personalized profile page
> - Bla bla

Comment: Not really a programming problem... But I can't see why not as you then miss out on revenue (along with Google).

Comment: I have other ways of making money once they're logged in.

Comment: But my point is, Google AdWords is there to make you money along with Google. If you chose not to display ads, then you're not making money via those ads, ergo you lose a revenue stream. Which is why I can't see it being a problem, as you're choosing where and when to show ads to suit your business model, it's really none of Google's business IMHO. I stand to be corrected of course ;)

Comment: Sorry, I need to know for sure.

Comment: Absolutely, just getting some commentary going. The only way you'll find out is to call / write to Google... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately there's no way to contact the AdSense team unless you make at least $50 a week.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that you would be in any trouble for offering an ad-free site for users who subscribe or log in. This is fairly common. Deciding to *not show ads at all* is at your discretion.

Google's [AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182) are focused toward preventing invalid and incentivized clicks. Your scenario is not mentioned at all.

The relevant parts:

> ### Invalid clicks and impressions
>
> Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate **impressions** and/or **clicks** artificially, including manual methods.
>
> Clicks on Google ads must result from genuine user interest. Any method that artificially generates clicks or impressions on your Google ads is strictly prohibited. These prohibited methods include, but are not limited to, repeated manual clicks or impressions, automated click and impression generating tools and the use of robots or deceptive software. **Please note that clicking your own ads for any reason is prohibited.**
>
> ### Encouraging clicks
>
> Publishers may not ask others to click their ads or use deceptive implementation methods to obtain clicks. This includes, but is not limited to, offering compensation to users for viewing ads or performing searches, promising to raise money for third parties for such behavior or placing images next to individual ads.
>
> In order to ensure a good experience for users and advertisers, publishers participating in the AdSense program may not:
>
> - Compensate users for viewing ads or performing searches, or promise compensation to a third party for such behavior.
> - Encourage users to click the Google ads using phrases such as "click the ads", "support us", "visit these links" or other similar language.
> - Direct user attention to the ads using arrows or other graphical gimmicks.
> - Place misleading images alongside individual ads.
> - Place ads in a floating box script.
> - Format ads so that they become indistinguishable from other content on that page.
> - Format site content so that it is difficult to distinguish it from ads.
> - Place misleading labels above Google ad units. For instance, ads may be labelled "Sponsored Links" or "Advertisements", but not "Favourite Sites" or "Today's Top Offers".

In fact, Google now has a program called [Contributor](https://www.google.com/contributor/welcome/) where people can pay a monthly fee and be shown fewer ads. The amount of money they pay is used in the live ad auction to bid against other ads, and when their automatic bid wins for an ad unit, contributors see a "Thanks for contributing" block instead of an ad. You receive the same percentage of that monthly fee as you would for the ads that would otherwise have been shown.